# Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 install giving black screen on reboot

Tags: boot

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 tonight on a SDD that's separate from my windows 10 drive. Says the install was successful, so i rebooted and removed my usb stick i used to install it. Now, just stops on a black screen after the reboot and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to boot with the LiveCD version to see if you can mount the partitions and check the disk?

Did you removed the USB stick when the message "Remove the installation media and press ENTER to continue" shows? I had a problem once when i forgot to remove the USB stick and the installation started again. I removed the stick in the middle of the process and somehow the previous installation was corrupted.